# How to keep count of different components from a list in unity tower defense game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

So I made a public struct for 'Tower' which includes all the variables for a tower in my Tower defense game.

```
public struct Tower
{

// Variables for Tower

public string Name;
public int type, Price, Count;
public float range, Cooldown, CurrCooldown;
public Sprite Spr;




public Tower(string Name, int type, float range, float cd, int Price, int Count, string path)
{
    this.Name = Name;
    this.type = type;
    this.range = range;
    this.Count = Count;
    Cooldown = cd;
    this.Price = Price;
    Spr = Resources.Load<Sprite> (path);
    CurrCooldown = 0;

}
```

Later in the script, I have a public enum for the tower types, which are given the stats of the variables from the Tower struct.

```
public enum TowerType // The type of tower selected. Each have different stats based on public lists (see below)

{
    FIRST_TOWER,
    SECOND_TOWER,
    THIRD_TOWER

}
```

I made a public list for the towers

```
public class GameControllerScr : MonoBehaviour {

public List<Tower> AllTowers = new List<Tower> ();
```

And added the unique variable values for each tower type

```
private void Awake()

{
    AllTowers.Add (new Tower ("Laser Piercer", 0, 2, .5f, 20, 1, "TowerSprites/FTower")); // Name, type, range, Cooldown, price
    AllTowers.Add (new Tower ("Horde Destroyer", 1, 3, 3f, 40, 2, "TowerSprites/STower"));
    AllTowers.Add (new Tower ("Freeze Ray", 2, 2, 1f, 30, 3, "TowerSprites/TTower"));
```

What I would like to know is how I can have a 'TowerCount' for each tower. In my game, you can build a tower anywhere on the map, and the player has the choice to choose either one of the three towers in the shop panel.

```
public void BuildTower(Tower tower) // Method for building a tower on a clicked cell.
{
    GameObject tmpTower = Instantiate (TowerPref);
    tmpTower.transform.SetParent (transform, false);
    Vector2 towerPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x + tmpTower.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.x / 2,
                                   transform.position.y - tmpTower.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.y / 2);


    tmpTower.transform.position = towerPos;


    tmpTower.GetComponent<TowerScr> ().selfType = (TowerType)tower.type;

    SelfTower = tmpTower;
    FindObjectOfType<ShopScr> ().CloseShop ();


}
```

How can I differentiate each tower apart, and create a seperate variables which changes based on the number of a tower's type on the map (e.g. there are 3 type1 towers, 2 type2 towers, and 0 type3 towers).

Answer (score 0):

An option that you could explore is in the Tower component script, or whatever script that is attached to each object, you could include a static list that you could easily reference.

I'm not familiar with your code enough to know of what class it would be. But let's say that you have a component on every tower that is called, "TowerComponent". So you could have:

```
public class TowerComponent: MonoBehaviour
{
   public static Dictionary<TowerComponent, TowerType> currentTowers = 
      new Dictionary<TowerComponent, TowerType>();

   private void Awake()
   {
      currentTowers.Add(this, typeOfTower);
   }
}
```

This will basically just say that everytime a tower comes into the scene, it will automatically add itself to a dictionary of references to themselves that you can reference from anywhere. You'll be able to say:

```
TowerComponent.curentTowers.Count(x=>x.value == towerType);
```

And that will return you the count of the tower types that you're looking for in any script. This will cause a dependency, but it is a way to get what you're after.